# Category For Pages In WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to categorize search result of WordPress, I have done that through adding categories to posts and custom post types. Now, only pages are listing without any category, I think it is possible to add category to pages as well, but I am not aware of its consequences.

Kindly you share your thoughts and experience.

Thank you

Comment: The `page` post type is not meant to have categories. The issue is, non of the page related functions is set up to accept or work with categories.

Comment: @PieterGoosen, thank you, but I just need categorize pages in search result, I won't use category for any other purpose, will it cause any performance issue?

Comment: No, it should not. I just feel you are sorting wrongly on your search page. Do you really need pages categorized to do the sorting

Comment: @PieterGoosen, thank you, I created search page which will display contents in categorized, for example when we search for music, it will list contents and contents will be categorized by Rock, Jazz, Pop,etc... Now client need to categorized pages like 'Help',   'Contact Forms', etc...

Comment: you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-tags-and-categories-for-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't provides option to create category in pages .

One thing that can be done is modification in search query
This will search you in  all the pages only.

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
       $query->set('post_type', 'page');
    }
    return $query;
    }

    add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Add this hook on some specific conditions, when you want only pages to be displayed in searches.

Other side will be to display everything other than pages . In that you will have to exclude the pages by their ID's

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
       $excludeId = array(23,23,23);
       $query->set('post__not_in', array($excludeId));
    }
    return $query;
    }

    add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Comment: Brittle solution. You shouldn't be putting page IDs into templates.

Comment: okay, you can get all the page IDs that needs to be excluded in an array by using Wp_Query

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not natively have a global taxonomy which is what you want. Categories in WordPress are tied to blog posts.

To accomplish this, I would use a combination of the incredible [`Advanced Custom Fields`](http://advancedcustomfields.com) (ACF) plugin and modifying `functions.php` to add a custom taxonomy to your site and apply it to all of your post-types.

### Step 1

In functions.php, make a custom taxonomy like this (modify for your needs):

```
// add_action registers the taxonomy into wordpress
add_action( 'init', 'setup_my_tax' );

// this function sets up the taxonomy to whatever standards you want
// reference register_taxonomy on codex.wordpress.org
function setup_my_tax() 

  // first parameter becomes the slug of the tax
  register_taxonomy( 'capabilities', array( 'post' ), array(

    // labels will determine how it show up in a menu
    'labels' => array(
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New ',
      'all_items' => 'All Capabilities',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Capability',
      'menu_name' => 'Capabilities',
      'name' => 'Capabilities',
      'new_item' => 'New Capability',
      'not_found' => 'No Capabilities Found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Capabilities Found in Trash',
      'parent' => 'Parent of Capability',
      'search_items' => 'Search Capabilities',
      'singular_name' => 'Capability',
      'view_item' => 'View Capability'
    ),

    // important individual settings from register_taxonomy
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui' => true
  ));
}
```

### Step 2

With ACF installed, you'll use the GUI to make a custom field set that contains this taxonomy. Below the custom field set are `rule` options that show you how to apply the custom bit to all of your entities.

[image]

### Step 3

In `page.php` and other templates you can make reference to your taxonomy terms like this:

```
// Put the capabilities into an array variable
$capObjects = get_field('capabilities');

// Iterate through the the array of tags and output them
// In WordPress, you have to use the term ID to lookup the term name
foreach ($capObjects as $capObject):
  echo '<li class="capabilities-item">';
  echo '<a href="' . get_term_link($capObject) . '">' . $capObject->name . '</a> ';
  echo '</li>';
endforeach;
```

You can now adjust your search template by a true tag that spans all of your types of content.